# Preferred way to set meta data / title and so on in Node.js / Express at dynamic pages?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I search for a good way to pass data to my html head, so I need a custom title, a meta description and so on, for every page on my project.

Spontaneously I see a way to pass the data per res.render, like:

```
app.get('/site_a', function(req, res) {
  res.render('stite_a', { 'title' : 'blablalalbalba', 'desc' : 'asdasdasd' });
});
```

That way I have to edit this for every route, what is maybe a nice choice for very small websites, but i need a more decent way. For X static pages and Y user generated pages, like a blog or something in this way.

I found then this example at the [Express reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals):

```
app.locals({
  title: 'My App',
  phone: '1-250-858-9990',
  email: 'me@myapp.com'
});
```

But I don't see how this will take me any further. In fact I want to do it a more dynamic way, say a user has a chance to change a title. This will lead me to my DB. So for my static pages I see a solution with this locals, pretty easy, but what is with pages generated by users?

Long story short, is there a preferred way with Node.js / Express to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`res.locals`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.locals).

You could set a 'default' with `app.locals` and then change it when you need it in a route.

Comment: This reference doesn't provide much infos, but I will take a look, maybe a few other sources for res.locals come up. Thanks anyway @Neikos.